# How to get the page thumbnail's url with WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I'm trying to get the url of a page's thumbnail from a certain category. With a snippet in functions.php i added the post thumbnails to pages. But now i want the grab the url of a page's thumbnail, but that doesn't seems to work. I get the post thumbnail of blogpost instead.

How can i fix this?

My current query:

```
$argpostthumbs = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'post_per_page'     => 1,
    'cat'               => $category->term_id,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
);
$postthumbs = new WP_Query($argpostthumbs);                                    

if ( $postthumbs->have_posts() ) {
    $imagePath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'fp-category-thumbnail' );
}
```

$imagepath contains the blogpost's thumbnail. I need the page thumbnail.

The snippet in functions.php:

```
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_and_tag_archives' );
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me with this. :)

Comment: _“I get the post thumbnail of blogpost instead”_ - well that’s because you are using the id of the post ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/: _“Retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.”_ Doesn’t look like you are inside the loop here ... So you need to get the post object first, and then get the id from that.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention. The code above is inside a foreach which is inside the loop.
I'm trying to achieve a list of categories which contains the thumbnail of the latest posted thumbnail of a post or page. Post is working, but page not yet.

Comment: Well you still need to call the_post then ...

Comment: so you had taxonomy under default wordpress page where you have several categories and trying to access the thumbnail..

Comment: @sagar Yes, i enabled category for the page. By default Wordpress is not supporting categories with pages.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail_url();
}
```

Comment: I just did. Didn't give me the outcome i was looking for. Above's code is part of a foreach loop, with your suggestion all the foreach queries gets the same thumbnail url. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are trying to have a category image or a single pages image, or maybe a categories image on a single page?
Do you have theme_support enabled for pages?

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) );
```

Also make sure you are in the right template, and inside a loop. Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment the questions in!

Comment: I checked. I've got thumbnails enabled for posts and pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this must work if you have placed all the codes correctly

```
$img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'full');
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that when i am back at work next week.

Comment: This didn't work. It was even worse. I got an array back. I didn't had that before.

Comment: Well let me look at this in my localhost then

Comment: For some reason it seems to ignore the post_type in the wp_query. Get the same thing when i remove that.